# How to use intent when testing Android classes?

Tags: android, testing, android-intent

here is some sample code, it seems that it doesn't work for me.

```
public class CropImageTest extends ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2<CropImage> {

    private Instrumentation mInstrumentation;
    private CropImage mActivity;
    private String filename = "/mnt/sdcard/DCIM/Camera/2011-05-12 09.22.56.jpg";
    private int aspectX = 1;
    private int aspectY = 1;
    private boolean scale = true;

    public CropImageTest() {
        super("hk.com.novare.android.cropimage", CropImage.class);
    }

    @Override
    protected void setUp() throws Exception {
        super.setUp();
        this.mInstrumentation = getInstrumentation();
        Intent i = new Intent(mInstrumentation.getContext(), CropImage.class);

        i.putExtra("image-path", filename);
        i.putExtra("aspectY", aspectY);
        i.putExtra("aspectX", aspectX);
        i.putExtra("scale", scale);
        setActivityIntent(i);
        mActivity = this.getActivity();  
    }

    public void testExtras() {
        String str = "";
        str = mActivity.getIntent().getStringExtra("image-path");
        assertEquals(filename, str);
    }
}
```

error encountered:

> Unable to resolve activity for: Intent ( has Extras )

my manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          android:versionCode="1"
          android:versionName="1.0"
          package="hk.com.novare.android.cropimage.tests">

    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8"/>
    <instrumentation
            android:targetPackage="hk.com.novare.android.cropimage"
            android:name="android.test.InstrumentationTestRunner"/>
    <application
            android:icon="@drawable/icon"
            android:label="@string/app_name">
        <uses-library android:name="android.test.runner"/>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

I encountered the error above even if I set the constructor -> super's string(a package ) same as the one that I've indicated within this test project's manifest.xml.
please help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think all you need to do is use

```
Intent i = new Intent();
```

See, for instance, the answers on [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4320099/how-do-i-write-an-android-junit-test-when-my-activity-relies-on-extras-passed-thr).

Comment: I've done this before, but it doesn't seem to work, I have the same error of "Unable to resolve activity for: Intent {flg=0x10000000 cmp=hk.com.novare.android.cropimage/.CropImage (has extras)}"

Comment: Silly question, I think, given the package name, but is `CropImage` a listed activity in the manifest for hk.com.novare.android.cropimage?

Comment: a forgotten question, should select the closest one, thanks however! :D

Answer (score 1):

While creating the intent you are passing `getInstrumentation().getContext()` which is the test app's context.

what you want is `getInstrumentation().getTargetContext()` which is the target application's context.

Answer (score 0):

When constructing the Intent, I think instead of `mInstrumentation.getContext()` you want to call `getActivity()`. I'm assuming that CropImage class is actually in the package under test, not the test package.

Comment: yep, but it is the one that should get and process the extras, so it doesn't make sense. and as the documentation indicates, you must not call getActivity() method before setActivityIntent()! :((